# Report wont run when using OLE DB connection

Tags: reporting-services, report, oledb

I have an SSRS Report it works perfectly when I use Oracle data source. However, when I tried to connect using OLEDB connection I am running into some issues.

**0x80040e10 in the message file for OraOLEDB**

I understand that its not receiving my parameter values.

For this report, I am using the date filters and applying to the report dataset in this manner

**where trunc(addwhen) between (:sd) and (:ed)**

Please can any help me figure out why I an running into this issue. It will be great help

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as you know,its not receiving your parameter values.

This is because, Trunc is not a sql query, Try using CAST() or CONVERT() which serves the purpose